# How to post data in Responder Python

Tags: python

I am using [Responder](https://python-responder.org/en/latest/), a python package for creating web api. In the documentation I could not find how to make a post request.

**how to make post request in responder ?**

Comment: Responder looks like it's a web server framework, meaning that you're not going to be able to make post requests in responder since that's not what it's designed for. If you need to generate a post request for one of your responses you might look at [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), which is a package designed to make http requests.

Comment: Do you want to *accept* or *make* a HTTP POST request?

Comment: @DaichiJameson Ohh. I did not see that coming. Will look into it and ask more specific question.

Comment: @LutzHorn I want to make a HTTP POST request.

Comment: Look at this page: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/